# ffmpeg, overlay .mov onto .mp4, way to make faster, without changing preset?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have the following command, which puts an overlay.mov file ontop of a .mp4 file.  It works great but i'm wondering if the command i'm using can be sped up.

```
ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -i 'assets/videos/background.mp4' -i 'assets/videos/overlay.mov' -filter_complex '[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[ua][b];[ua]setsar=1,format=yuva444p,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[u];[b][u]overlay=eof_action=pass[v]' -map [v] -map 0:a -preset medium -y 'assets/videos/output.mov'
```

I know i can change `-preset` to `ultrafast` but is there a way i can improve the above command?  Anything obsolete?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to reencode video you can use the same codec, ffmpeg just move mov format to mp4 format, and It very fast.

```
 ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v copy out.mp4
```